# Java, dynamic class loading from github sources

Tags: java, dynamic, github, classloader

Okay, so I am trying the following:

I have java-files on github. I want to load these dynamic at runtime. Is there any possibility to do so ? I think a URLClassLoader is not working, because I dont have an URL to the containing folder of the files, I only have an URL to the file itself.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- download the java file to the local system
- use a [JavaCompiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) with a StandardJavaFileManager (cf example in JavaCompiler javadoc) to compiler the java file to a class file that you can save on the local system
- use a URLClassLoader to load the class file